# How to block users during the test phase?

Tags: testing, release-management

Even with proper testing in lower tiers (unit testing, static analysis, hallway usability testing, etc.) we have to conduct some minimal tests again in PROD once the releases are deployed.

Assuming that we want to block the users during the testing phase. Why? So they won't face any inconsistencies in case some anomaly manifests itself in PROD. e.g., conflicts caused by some automated testing routine, corrupt data, etc.

I've seen applications that are:

1. Blocked through network rules, i.e., only the IP addresses of the QA
   users are allowed to access the app.
2. Blocked by a proxy/SSO server based on their credentials.

I've implemented option #2 as I have more control over the process (since I'm avoiding unnecessary iterations with the Network team), what would be your method of choice? OR do you have an alternative to PROD tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prod testing is important.

Stopping random users from accessing the system while you are conducting prod tests does matter.

Beyond that, so long as you have means that are reasonably simple/straightforwards/reliable and don't introduce new bugs/issues of their own, then there is no need to overthink things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tim_B, could you present any tangible options/concepts for "means that are reasonably simple/straightforwards/reliable" ?

Comment: Limiting login to a certain role (assuming your site requires login), removing external network access, using server settings to redirect users to an "upgrade in progress page" unless they come from an internal ip, the methods you listed yourself, etc. It all depends on the nature of the product you are presenting and how you want to present the downtime to the end user.

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world you have a failover environment... While deploying and testing the upgraded system, production can run on the failover, once you are happy you cut over to the upgraded system.

This comes with the risk that if failover itself fails and you are unhappy with testing you have nowhere to go

Comment: So, you are suggesting the network path, i.e., configure the load balancer to point to the failover environment. Assuming it's an active/passive system (1 environment remains in standby mode), how to elegantly block unwanted users?

Comment: Yes, update the load balancer. Unwanted users should have no access to the system anymore. The problem would be already logged in users, but those you just have to bump off. Somehow you also need to make your users aware that an upgrade will be taking place